# Construct examples of minimally 2-connected graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a 2-connected graph, $G$ is minimally 2-connected if for any $e \in E(G)$, $G-e$ is not 2-connected. For each number $n$, construct a minimally 2-connected graph with a vertex of degree at least $n$.

I tried using the bipartite and similar graphs to construct such examples. But I never succeeded in finding them. Is there a clever way to construct such graphs? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,2}$. Removing any edge from this graph will always leave one vertex $v$ having degree 1; after removing the edge, removing the single vertex adjacent to $v$ will disconnect the graph.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n$, take $\lceil \frac n2 \rceil$ copies of $C_5$, the cycle graph with five vertices. Then, choose a vertex in each of the copies, and identify all these vertices. The resulting vertex has degree $n$ or $n + 1$; if you remove any edge from this graph, it remains connected, but by removing a different edge from the same cycle you can always disconnect it.

Comment: Your graph is not even $2$-connected, since removing the identified vertex disconnects the graph.